# Django Realtime Checking Database Data

Tags: django, database, real-time

I'm developing a web with Django. How do I display of other web activity user recorded in the my database(Real Time)  such as wall of Facebook. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at

http://swampdragon.net

Github

https://github.com/jonashagstedt/swampdragon

Tutorials

http://swampdragon.net/tutorial/part-1-here-be-dragons-and-thats-a-good-thing/

Comment: If this answer was helpful, don't forget to accept it as an answer :-) http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer